# How to use dictionary of tuple-value pairs to fill pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
dc ={(a,b):0.4, (a,c):0.3, (b,c):0.2}
```

I would like to fill an existing pandas dataframe which is of the form:

```
df

     a       b       c
a    0       1       0
b   0.3      1       1
c    1       0       0
```

to:

```
new_df

     a       b       c
a    0       0.4     0.3
b   0.4      0       0.2
c   0.3      0.2      0
```

It doesn't really matter what the values in the existing cells are, I need to replace all of them (and set the ones not in the dictionary pairs to 0).

My eventual goal is to create a networks graph out of these.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `update`

```
df.update(pd.Series(d).unstack())
df.update(pd.Series(d).unstack().T)
df
Out[71]: 
     a    b    c
a  0.0  0.4  0.3
b  0.4  0.0  0.2
c  0.3  0.2  0.0
```

More info

```
pd.Series(d).unstack()
Out[66]: 
     b    c
a  0.4  0.3
b  NaN  0.2
```